# How to find or track where a function is being called from?

Tags: reactjs

I have a very intricate site that is quite large. I would attempt to post the code but that may be more work posting the code to display the multiple connections.

Anyways, on this site, I have a component which calls a specific function whenever there is a change. The problem is within that function, when in a specific if block it keeps rerendering after then setState.

I was wondering if there is any way that we can track where a function is being called in react. I tried debugging using console.log but never recieved much information from this.

Any help at all would be appreciated.

Comment: Use the debbuger keyword to track each time the browser engine runs through it.

Comment: You can use performance tab in Chrome console. It will show you which functions are worked slowly. Just take a snapshot from the performance tab of Chrome.

Comment: It sounds like your render function is modifying the `this.state`. If the `this.state` changes that may trigger a render which will cause an infinite loop.

Comment: @sissonb I removed all the set state calls in that function where the issue is and it still falls back in into an infinite loop.